# Magento2 How to display a text in between the shipping address street line 1 and 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shipping, shipping-address

I would like to display some text as a note between the shipping address street line 1 and line 2. Can anyone tell me how to do this ? I am not able to find the template of the text fields of street address.

Answer (score 0):

Street address is rendering from {process() function in Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor} then it called {merge() and getMultilineFieldConfig() function in Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger}.

You can take reference or add tooltip like Phone number please refer following link:

[How to add tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55728888/how-to-add-tooltip-on-magento-2-checkout-on-street-address-field)